# Laravel - Edit page not found

Tags: php, laravel

I'm showing all my articles in the category index page and when clicking on edit an article is says page not found. I think the problem is that i have two ids in the url example: category/5/article/1/edit. But the url needs to be article/1/edit.

```
<a href="article/{{ $article->id }}/edit">Edit</a>
```

```
Route::resource('category', 'CategoryController');
Route::resource('article', 'ArticleController');
```

Comment: can you share your routes file code?

Comment: Can you clarify which is the wanted url result? Is it /article/1/edit or /cartegory/2/artucke/1/edit

Comment: /article/1/edit

Comment: run : php artisan route:list  in cmd to check if edit route exist

Comment: Can you share your controller, maybe "ArticleController" with the edit method. Are you retuning the method to a view?

Answer (score 3):

Clean version:

```
<a href="{{ route('articles.edit', $article->id) }}">Edit</a>
```

Will create url with id of edited "model/resource":

```
articles/{id}/edit
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the resource routes/controller you could use the `route()` function and pass the route name as the first parameter, and the article id as the second:

```
<a href="{{ route('articles.edit', $article->id) }}">Edit</a>
```

For more info: [click here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers).

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
<a href="{{ url('article/'.$article->id.'/edit')}}">Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

When we make a route as resource (eg.article),it creates a named 
         route article.edit.The url will be article/{id}/edit.

In web.php

```
Route::resource('article', 'ArticleController');
```

In view

```
    <a href="{{ route('article.edit', ['id' => $article->id]) }}"> </a>
```

its similar to article/{id}/edit url

Comment: Hi, please expand on your answer as to why this would be a solution to OP's issue. This will help OP and future visitors of the site. Thanks!